# Dynamically adding active class on a link based on the window location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an `active` class dynamically on `<a>` tag based on the location pathname.

Both `pathname` and `href` values are the same. However, I can't see `active` class being added based on the jquery code I have written. I can't figure out what exactly I am missing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  $('.br-sideleft .br-sideleft-menu').find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.br-sideleft .br-sideleft-menu li a').each(function() {
    if (this.href == pathname) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="br-sideleft">
  <ul class="br-sideleft-menu">
    <li class="br-menu-item">
      <a class="br-menu-link active" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Link 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="br-sideleft-menu">
    <li class="br-menu-item">
      <a class="br-menu-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Page2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="br-menu-item">
      <a class="br-menu-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Page3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="br-sideleft-menu">
    <li class="br-menu-item">
      <a class="br-menu-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Page4">Link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="br-menu-item">
      <a class="br-menu-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Page5">Link 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure: `console.log(this.href, pathname)`

Comment: Where do you assign your `<a>` tags an `href`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `if` condition is not correct:

```
$('.br-sideleft .br-sideleft-menu li a').each(function() {
    if (this.href == pathname) { //this is wrong
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

change it to:

```
$('.br-sideleft .br-sideleft-menu li a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == pathname) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thanks

Comment: you can mark the question with the green hook to let other users know that this solves the issue ;) glad to here its working

Comment: Yeah. I just need to wait for 10 mins before accepting the answer. SO rules!!

Comment: true that bro :D

Comment: It can also be closed as useless for future visitors

Comment: @mplungjan the answer or the topic itself?

Comment: The question. It is a duplicate in several ways :)

Comment: @mplungjan yes but this is the case in 70% of all posts here :D

Comment: Which is why a delete is more useful

Answer (score 0):

An approach i would take is to add a data attribute to anchor onto, this gives you the freedom to define routes that your list items link to and style them accordingly based on route...

```js
(() => {
  $('li')
  .filter((i, li) => $(li).data('route') === window.location.pathname)
  .addClass('active')
})()
```

```html
<li data-route="/">HOME</li>
<li data-route="/friends">Friends</li>
<li data-route="/profile">Profile</li>
<li data-route="/blog">Blog</li>
```

As you can see, i run over all the list-items and filter out all the items that do not have data-route attributes that match the window.location.pathname, after i am left with the filtered list, i apply an active class to the matched items.

*note* this is a generalised answer, hopefully the learning curve taken from the example translates into your answer :-)

Comment: this produces an error due to you have not added `jQuery` to the playground

Comment: My aim was for the code to be read and learned from and then maybe drop in a fiddle to check functionally works. not: click run, copy/paste into project & commit all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `console.log(this.href)` would show you that reading the href returns the whole url, not what you see in the attribute. So just read the pathname when you are comparing

```
$('.br-sideleft .br-sideleft-menu li a').filter(function() {
  return this.pathname == pathname
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Flag as typo-type or duplicate?